# My django smtp g-suite settings don't seem to be working

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, smtp, pythonanywhere

I am having issues connecting Django to google g-suite account:

The settings are currently as follows:

```
SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '16CharacterAppPassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Setting I have tried: Note, comma separated the different settings I have tried in all possible combination

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com', 'smtp-relay.gmail.com', 'mail.mydomain.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True, False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False, True
EMAIL_PORT = 587, 25, 465 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '16CharacterAppPassword', 'mynormalpassword'
```

Other things I have tried:

```
LessSecure settings: On/Off
App Password: Tried 2 two different ones just incase the first one messed up
Contact G-Suite support: They had a look at the settings and everything is fine from their end
Tried CaptchaLink
Tried verifying last login attempt as 'it was me' so it won't block the IP
```

Tried the following tutorial: [G-Suite Smtp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kXqX4RKeDU&ab_channel=RChrisFord.com)

More details if it might help:

```
Server: Pythonanywhere
Domain: Google registered domain

Python: 3.8
Django: 3.1.1
django-allauth: 0.42.0
```

Error msg I get when trying to send an email:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: Username and Password not accepted learn more at ...
```

Followed the link provided and tried all the trouble shoot methods.

EDIT:
After 48hrs it's randomly working and nothing has really changed in terms of what I have tried. I'll leave this open if someone knows what the cause might have been? Only thing I can think of is DNS Propagation but can't confirm since support mentioned that everything was fine their side.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the SITE_ID is wrong try to enter to the shell and get the right SITE_ID by this command:

```
 from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

    new_site = Site.objects.create(domain='....', name='....')

    print new_site.id
```

Comment: it's using `SITE_ID=1` already. Sorry, wasn't sure if that setting would affect it. Let me edit my question to mention this as well

Comment: Following that it prints out `3` for `new_site.id`

Comment: so change to SITE_ID=3

Comment: This still didn't work for me. But yesterday it just started working randomly with `SITE_ID=1`. I have no clue what changed since it wasn't working for the longest time. Pull old code from when it wasn't working and it works as well. Maybe something changed with gsuite?

Comment: I  encounter this problem 3 weeks ago  and i solve it by the method above anyway i'm happy for you that you solve it .